# How to remove the model of transformers in GPU memory

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

```
from transformers import CTRLTokenizer, TFCTRLLMHeadModel
tokenizer_ctrl = CTRLTokenizer.from_pretrained('ctrl', cache_dir='./cache', local_files_only=True)
model_ctrl = TFCTRLLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('ctrl', cache_dir='./cache', local_files_only=True)
print(tokenizer_ctrl)
gen_nlp  = pipeline("text-generation", model=model_ctrl, tokenizer=tokenizer_ctrl, device=1, return_full_text=False)
```

Hello, my codes can load the transformer model, for example, CTRL here, into the gpu memory.
How to remove it from GPU after usage, to free more gpu memory?

show I use `torch.cuda.empty_cache()` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply `del tokenizer_ctrl` and then use `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`.

See this [thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-delete-a-tensor-in-gpu-to-free-up-memory/48879/5) from pytorch forum discussing it.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I think we need to do some particular step for models. It correctly work for tensors, but it doesn't work for models.

Answer (score 0):

@pierlj's solution doesn't seem to work for transformer models, however this solution from the thread they linked works for me:

```
import gc

del model
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```